# "Ungrep" - which patterns aren't matched

Tags: grep

I'm looking for a command or script to do the following - given:

file1.txt:

```
abcd
efgh 
ijkl
mnop
```

file2.txt:

```
123abcd123
123efgh123
123mnop123
```

I want a command that does something like this:

```
ungrep file1.txt file2.txt
```

and returns the following:

```
ijkl
```

In other words it is giving me the lines in file1.txt that will not return any results on a grep of file2.txt. I know that I can do this by iterating through file1.txt, grepping file2.txt for each line and storing the result, and outputting any lines where the result is empty, but I was hoping for a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With GNU `grep` the following should work. Using the `-f` option, pass `file1.txt` as a "pattern file" - but also pass it in a second time as a data file. Use `-o` to report only the matching parts. Finally extracts those words that match only once - these correspond to the lines from `file1.txt` that do not find a match in `file2.txt`.

```
grep -h -o -f  file1.txt file2.txt file1.txt | sort | uniq -u
ijkl
```

Comment: Very good description.  Thanks and +1.

Comment: You could achieve the same effect without the grep trickiness: `sort file1.txt <(grep -of file1.txt file2.txt) | uniq -u`, but, like your solution, this only works when the pattern file doesn't actually contain any regex metacharacters.

Comment: @rici, that is a very good point

Comment: Improvement: `grep -oFf file1.txt file2.txt | sort file1.txt - | uniq -u`

Answer (score 10):

You could do it with `awk` like:

```
awk '
  NR == FNR {w[$0]; next}
  {for (i in w) if (index($0,i)) delete w[i]}
  END {for (i in w) print i}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

By using `index`, we're looking for substrings rather than matching regular expressions.

Because we delete the word from the array as soon as we find a match, we avoid unnecessary searches.

Comment: I would only accept this one. It does not invoke any O(n log n) sorting, and does not fail strangely when the patterns contain regex meta-characters, and could be extended to support regexes.

Comment: I can't believe that simply evaluating `w[$0]` has the side effect of adding the key to the array.

Comment: @Kaz, yes that can be confusing, and you find many scripts not knowingly allocating array elements unintentionally by doing `if (a[$1])` instead of `if ($1 in a)` for instance. It's the case of every `awk` including the original `awk` and `nawk`, but looking at the standard yesterday, I couldn't find it specified.

Comment: @Kaz: awk is a beautiful little tool ^^ I find it easier to read than perl (but of course slower and less powerfull, the latter which makes for the better readability as it has less single-character-special-variables ^^)

Comment: @Kaz Here's the POSIX quote: *"The application shall ensure that a multi-dimensioned index used with the **in** operator is parenthesized. The **in** operator, which tests for the existence of a particular array element, shall not cause that element to exist. Any other reference to a nonexistent array element shall automatically create it."*  It can be found by scrolling a paragraph or two up from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03).

Comment: As long as `file1` is not huge (for some value of huge), I'd prefer this solution as it doesn't require any sorting of `file2` and would be expected to be much more efficient.