# grep match multiple substrings and pass or fail on missing

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | \
grep -qi 'nginx/1.9.10\|ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10\|openssl-1.0.2f\|modsecurity-2.9.‌​0' \
&& echo "has the stuff we need" \
|| echo "missing something"
```

which is going against

```
[root@mage2appblock vagrant]# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.9.10
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --user=www-data --group=www-data
--prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid
--lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp
--add-module=/src/nginx/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10-beta
--add-module=/src/nginx/modsecurity-2.9.0/nginx/modsecurity 
--with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_mp4_module --with-http_flv_module 
--with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module
--with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_v2_module --with-http_ssl_module 
--with-openssl=/src/nginx/openssl-1.0.2f 
--with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl
--with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-pcre --with-ipv6 
--with-file-aio --with-http_realip_module 
--without-http_scgi_module --without-http_uwsgi_module
```

Seems that if I change the substrings from

```
'nginx/1.9.10\|ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10\|openssl-1.0.2f\|modsecurity-2.9.‌​0'
```

to

```
'nginx/1.9.10\|ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10\|openssl-1.0.2f\|modsecurity-2.9.‌​1'
```

I still get `"has the stuff we need"` even though not everything was present.  I need to match all or nothing.

Comment: | in grep-speak is "or", not "and"

Comment: try something along the lines of: nginx -V | grep string1 | grep string2 | grep string3... | grep -q last-string; if $? is 0, you found them all, otherwise you're missing one

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes I see that now.  ok, just need to re do for and `and` version, ok..

Comment: @JeffSchaller not 100% I'm following, but `out=$(nginx -V 2>&1); echo $out | grep -qi "nginx/1.9.10" | grep -qi "ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10" | grep -qi "openssl-1.0.2f" | grep -qi "modsecurity-2.9.0" && echo "has the stuff we need" || echo  "missing something"` is always hitting `"missing something"` when it is true..

Comment: don't use -q in the first greps; that prevents those greps from passing along the output to the subsequent greps

Comment: Is `grep` a requirement?

Comment: @JeffSchaller `echo $(nginx -V 2>&1) | grep -i "nginx/1.9.10" 2>&1 | grep -i "ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10" 2>&1 | grep -i "openssl-1.0.2f" 2>&1 | grep -i "modsecurity-2.9.0" 2>&1 && echo "has the stuff we need" || echo  "missing something"`  work, but I'm getting the output of `nginx -V` as well, which I only can get `has the stuff we need`

Comment: @HaukeLaging no it is not, just that it is a one liner, is match all or nothing, and is in this if else fashion I have for the echos

Comment: @JeffSchaller `echo $(nginx -V 2>&1) | grep -i "nginx/1.9.10" | grep -i "ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10" | grep -i "openssl-1.0.2f" | grep -qi "modsecurity-2.9.0"  && echo "has the stuff we need" || echo  "missing something"
` seems to be the ticket I think

Comment: Then leave the -q on the last grep....

Comment: @JeffSchaller yep just thought of that and posted back as you did

Comment: Similar: ["Ungrep" - which patterns aren't matched](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with a little modification:

```
[ $(nginx -V 2>&1 | 
    grep -cFf <(
        echo 'nginx/1.9.10
ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10
openssl-1.0.2f
modsecurity-2.9.0'
    )) -eq 4 ] &&
echo "has the stuff we need" ||
echo "missing something"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/openssl-1.0.2f/ {test1=1} /nginx\/1.9.10/ {test2=1} 
  END { if (test1 && test2) print "has the stuff we need"; 
  else print "missing something"}'
```

You can also set the exit code of `awk` if you need that.

**update**

shorter version (treats input with line breaks as a single "line" assuming the input does contain 0x1 characters)

```
awk -v RS='\1' '/openssl-1\.0\.2f/ && /nginx\/1\.9\.10/ {
 print "has the stuff we need"; exit};{print "missing something"; exit(1)}'
```

Comment: this seems like it would be a lot longer of a one liner then `echo $(nginx -V 2>&1) | grep -i "nginx/1.9.10" | grep -i "ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10" | grep -i "openssl-1.0.2f" | grep -qi "modsecurity-2.9.0"  && echo "has the stuff we need" || echo  "missing something"` is there a way to shorten yours?

Comment: @jeremy.bass Yes, can be done easier.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `perl` and slurp the file whole:

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | perl -0ne 'print "found\n" if m#nginx/1.9.10# && 
      /ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10/ && 
     /openssl-1.0.2f/ && /modsecurity-2.9.0/'
```

Also, note that you have some hidden characters in the text of your question. I don't know if those are also there in your actual search string but, if they are, they will cause you problems. If I copy the `modsecurity-2.9.‌​0` from your question and pass it through `od -c`, I get:

```
$ echo modsecurity-2.9.‌​0 | od -c
0000000   m   o   d   s   e   c   u   r   i   t   y   -   2   .   9   .
0000020 342 200 214 342 200 213   0  \n
0000030
```

Specifically, according to `uniprops`, you have 6 occurrences of [U+FFFD ‹�› \N{REPLACEMENT CHARACTER}](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) between the last `.` and the `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
has_all_iregexps() {
  awk '
    BEGIN {
      if (ARGC <= 1) exit
      for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) s[tolower(ARGV[i])]
      n = ARGC - 1
      ARGC = 1
    }
    {
      for (i in s) if (tolower($0) ~ i) {
        delete s[i]; if (!--n) exit
      }
    }
    END {
      if (n) {
        print "Those regexps were not matched:"
        for (i in s) print "  " i
        exit(1)
      }
    }' "$@" >&2
}
```

And then:

```
nginx -V 2>&1 |
  has_all_iregexps 'nginx/1\.9\.10' \
                   'ngx_pagespeed-release-1\.9\.32\.10' \
                   'openssl-1\.0\.2f' \
                   'modsecurity-2\.9\.‌​0' &&
  echo "has the stuff we need"
```

Or:

```
has_all_istrings() {
  awk '
    BEGIN {
      if (ARGC <= 1) exit
      for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) s[tolower(ARGV[i])]
      n = ARGC - 1
      ARGC = 1
    }
    {
      for (i in s) if (index(tolower($0), i)) {
        delete s[i]; if (!--n) exit
      }
    }
    END {
      if (n) {
        print "Those strings were not found:"
        for (i in s) print "  " i
        exit(1)
      }
    }' "$@" >&2
}

nginx -V 2>&1 |
  has_all_istrings 'nginx/1.9.10' \
                   'ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10' \
                   'openssl-1.0.2f' \
                   'modsecurity-2.9.‌​0' &&
  echo "has the stuff we need"
```

(the `tolower`s are for case insensitive matching to match your use of `-i`, though I'm not sure why you'd want to do case insensitive matching here).