# grep: Not a recognized flag in AIX

Tags: shell-script, grep, aix

I am trying to write a shell which will fetch a set of data from table and write it to a text file whose name is `result.txt` . Now I will pick each line from this file and search it in a log file and check if it present or not. If it is not found in the log file I want to write it in a separate file say `notfound.txt`. I am working on a AIX server and getting this below error for the `grep` command. Can somebody please help me figure out what's wrong?

Here is my script,

```
while read -r LINE; do
    grep -q "$LINE" log.log 
    if [  $? -eq 0 ]
    then
       echo "$LINE" >> /home/notfound.txt
    fi
done  < result.txt
```

which gives me following output,

> grep: Not a recognized flag: -
>   Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
>           [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
>
> Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L]  [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
>           -f pattern_file... [file...]
>
> Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...]

Comment: The name "notfound" seems contradictory.  The script prints the lines which *were* found in the log.

Comment: rather than assuming what you have in that two files, it would be better for us if you post sample content of these two files in your question.

Comment: @tripleee looks like logic error.. I will fix that

Comment: See also ["Ungrep" - which patterns aren't matched](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80173) for a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Note that to read a line with `read`, the syntax is [`IFS= read -r line`](/q/209123). Without `IFS=`, blanks are stripped from the beginning and end of the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `$LINE` contains a value which starts with a dash.

You can protect against this with

```
grep -q -e "$LINE"
```

More generally, most Unix commands allow `--` to mark the end of options, and so any argument after this "end of options" option will be taken as a literal, non-option argument.

`echo` will have a problem, too; the portable solution is to switch to `printf`, which works fine with arguments which start with dashes, as long as it's not the first argument, which is a format string.

You should also avoid using uppercase variable names; these are reserved for system use.

Finally, scripts should almost never need to explicitly examine `$?` - this is already done by `if`, `while` and other control constructs.

```
if grep -q -e "$line" log.log; then
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
fi
```

As an optimization, placing the redirection outside the loop will make things a lot quicker.

```
while read -r line; do
    grep -q -e "$line" log.log && printf '%s\n' "$line"
done <results.txt >notfound.txt
```

Comment: These is also the `--` parameter, which will not parse any further parameters with a leading hyphen as though they are switches.  `grep -q -- "$pattern" "$haystack"`.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks your response. Will the second option check for each and every line from results.txt in log.log ? Also with the word dash what are you referring to ?

Comment: The dash character (aka hyphen, minus, [ASCII 0x2d](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm)) is used to introduce options to Unix commands.  To use it as a regular non-option argument, you need to disambiguate it somehow.

Comment: @tripleee Can I possibly start reading my file possibly from the nth LIne and stop just at the second last line ?

Comment: If you have a new question which is unrelated to this one, ask a new question.  But yes, what you are describing can be done, though it sounds like you should be looking at Awk.  I was actually thinking that you should probably be using Awk for this task as well.

Comment: See also the `-F` option if those `$line` are meant to be fixed text to search for as opposed to regular expressions, and `-x` if they are to matched as the full line.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ack, updated.  I originally suggested `grep -f result.txt log.log` but that will print the matching line, not the matching expression.  Not sure what the OP wants to accomplish so leaving it at this.